# Modifying python script to work with version 3.7.6

Tags: python-3.x

I currently host the English Amiga Board (EAB) FTP, a FTP server filled with the classic Amiga computer goodies. It is open to everyone but users can also register their own account. I got help in creating a python script that checks that the username being registered at the FTP is a valid account on the EAB forums and that it has at least 50 posts.

However, I've now updated the server (fedora server) and the Python version was updated to 3.7.6. The script have now stopped working and I'm unable to reach the original author.

```
# python ./eab_post_count.py -u Turran
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./eab_post_count.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sys, re, urllib2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'
```

This script should return "0" if the user exists and have 50 posts.

While I script in some languages, python is not one of them so I would be grateful for any help to modify it to not use urllib2, which I understand is no longer valid for Python 3.

The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import sys, re, urllib2

titlecmd = "eab_post_count.py"
version = "1.15"
ignorecase = 0
lastpost = 0
userfound = False

if len(sys.argv) == 1: sys.argv[1:] = ["-h"]

def parseurl(url):
    if not url:
        print("Empty URL!")
        sys.exit(3)
    headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0' }
    request = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
    try: 
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    except Exception:
        print('URL open failed, EAB down?')
        sys.exit(2)
    content = response.read()
    return content

def pagesearch(content, trigger, start, end):
    sane = 0
    needlestack = []
    while sane == 0:
        curpos = content.find(trigger)
        if curpos >= 0:
            testlen = len(content)
            content = content[curpos:testlen]
            curpos = content.find('"')
            testlen = len(content)
            content = content[curpos+1:testlen]
            curpos = content.find(end)
            needle = content[0:curpos]
            result = content[len(start):curpos]
            if needle.startswith(start):
                needlestack.append(result)
        else:
            sane = 1
    return needlestack

def unescape(s):
    s = s.replace("&lt;", "<")
    s = s.replace("&gt;", ">")
    # this has to be last:
    s = s.replace("&amp;", "&")
    return s

for idx, arg in enumerate(sys.argv):
    if arg == '-h':
        print(titlecmd + ' v' + version +' by modrobert in 2017')
        print('Function: Returns the number of posts for a given EAB forum user.')
        print('Syntax  : ' + titlecmd + ' -u <username> [-i] [-l YYYY-MM-DD]')
        print('Options : -h this help text.')
        print('        : -i ignore case sensivity in user name.')
        print('          -l last post after YYYY-MM-DD required.')
        print('          -u followed by user name.')
        print('Result  : 0 = user found, 1 = user not found, 2 = EAB down, 3 = other fail.')
        sys.exit(3)
    if arg == '-u':
        try:
            username = sys.argv[idx+1]
        except IndexError:
            print('Missing username.')
            sys.exit(3)
        usernameurl = re.sub('[ ]', '%20', username)
    if arg == '-i':
        ignorecase = 1
    if arg == '-l':
        lastpost = 1
        try:
            lpdate = sys.argv[idx+1]
        except IndexError:
            print('Missing date.')
            sys.exit(3)
try:
    username
except NameError:
    print('Username -u option required.')
    sys.exit(3)

if lastpost:
    eaburl = "http://eab.abime.net/memberlist.php?do=getall&pp=100&lastpostafter=" + lpdate + "&ausername=" + usernameurl
else:
    eaburl = "http://eab.abime.net/memberlist.php?do=getall&pp=100&ausername=" + usernameurl

eabcontent = parseurl(eaburl)

countlist = pagesearch(eabcontent, 'td class', 'alt2">', '</td>')
userlist = pagesearch(eabcontent, 'member.php?', '>', '</a>')


for idx, item in enumerate(userlist):
    # lets strip those fancy moderators and admins
    userstr = re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', item)
    if ignorecase:
        if unescape(str.lower(userstr)) == str.lower(username):
            userfound = True;
            break
    else:
        if unescape(str(userstr)) == username:
            userfound = True; 
            break

if userfound == False:
    print("User not found: " + username)
    sys.exit(1)

usercount = idx

for idx, item in enumerate(countlist):
    # hairy stuff below ;)
    if idx < (3 * usercount):
        continue
    stripitem = re.sub('[,]', '', item)
    try:
        print(int(stripitem))
        sys.exit(0)
    except Exception:
        continue
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems that you want to port code from Python 2 to Python 3. Be aware that there may be more differences than just ``urllib``. Are you aware of the [Porting Python 2 Code to Python 3 Howto](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html)?

Comment: I did not, thanks. While, as I wrote, I do not know python at all, the article gave me an idea to simply call /usr/bin/python2 when launching the script and it works. That gives me some time to reach the developer. Thanks!